# Concept for a type that checks if a class is one specified template class, which is parametrized by types, that satisfy another concept

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Lets say I have a function in C++17:

```cpp
template<typename Range> void calculate(const Range& range) { /* do something */ }
```

And I want to specialize it for all pairs of integral types (`std::pair<std::integral, std::integral>`), and I want to create a separate concept `IntegralRange` for it: how can I achieve it?

Comment: If you already are committing to the `std::pair` why not just use a `template<std::integral I> void calculate(const std::pair<I, I>& range) { ... }`?

Comment: @JakobStark because  `std::pair<int, long>` is also a valid argument, also in my actual case I have multiple template parameters and argumets, so I cant just change from `template<typename Range>` to `template<std::integral LBound, std::integral RBound>` because of API compatibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specializing the function for this purpose isn't possible; I assume you meant overloading. You can solve this problem by providing as second overload:

```cpp
template<std::integral First, std::integral Second>
void calculate(std::pair<First, Second> range) { /* do something */ }
```

Alternatively, if you insist on using a concept:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept integral_pair = requires (T pair) {
    []<std::integral First, std::integral Second>(std::pair<First, Second>){}(pair);
};

void calculate(integral_pair auto range) { /* do something */ }
```

The `requires` expression uses an immediately invoked lambda expression (IILE) to ensure that `First` and `Second` can be deduced from `pair`.